# How to replace special character in string with tcl script?

Tags: tcl

In file.txt

```
obj = "hi/this/is[1]/script"
```

convert the string to

```
obj = "hi/this/is\[1]/script"
```

Is there a way to do this in tcl?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace all occurrences of a character, `string map` is pretty suitable:

```
# Careful with the quoting here
set obj [string map [list {[} {\[}] $obj]
```

If you want to just replace the first occurrence, `regsub` is a better tool

```
set obj [regsub {\[} $obj {\\&}]
```

(The `&` becomes the matched string, and we need to be careful with backslashes in both the RE and the substitution text.)

Comment: Incase if you want to replace both the square brackets in all occurrences you can use "regsub -all (\\\[|\\\]) $obj {\\\1} obj"

Answer (score 0):

One way is using [`string map`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34):

```
% set obj {obj = "hi/this/is[1]/script"}
obj = "hi/this/is[1]/script"
% string map {\[ \\\[} $obj
obj = "hi/this/is\[1]/script"
```